# Getting feature information from selection ol3

Tags: openlayers-3

I am using Openlayers 3 and would like to create a graph real time from information contained on a selected object. I need to access the properties, but get('myfield') is not working. My features are in a GeoJSON vector layer.

```
var selectSingleClick = new ol.interaction.Select();
map.addInteraction(selectSingleClick);


map.on('singleclick', function(event){  
    mylayer.once('precompose',function(event){
      var selectedFeatures = selectSingleClick.getFeatures();
      readFeature(selectedFeatures);
    });
});

function readFeature(features){
    consoleText = document.getElementById('console');
//  When selected, getLength() returns 1, so selection is working.
//  consoleText.innerHTML = features.getLength();
    var myfeature = features[0];
    consoleText.innerHTML += myfeature.get('objectId');
}
```

Anybody can help me to understand what is going wrong? I have not much experience with Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

I have found my problem. Trying to access the features by

```
var myfeature = features[0];
```

Correct syntax should be:

```
var myfeature = features.item(0);
```

But in previous examples features[0] have worked. Would be keen to understand why this is so...

Answer (score 1):

If u look at the documentation of openlayers 3
http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.interaction.Select.html#getFeatures
    `selectSingleClick.getFeatures()`
returns ol.Collection() object which is an enhancement over normal Javascript array object.
For more information on ol.Collection() have a look at this link.
http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Collection.html

```
var myfeature = features[0];
```

is normal way to get an object from an array.